# Elasticsearch version conflict

Tags: elasticsearch

I have updated document in the elastic search. after update using I am fetching the same document by using their ID. It is giving me following response:

```
 {
"_index": "b123456",
"_type": "documents",
"_id": "bltde56dd11ba998bab",
"_version": 3,
"found": true,
"_source": {
    "title": "index.json",
    "url": "/index1",
    "tags": [],
    "created_at": "2018-06-19T05:02:38.174Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-06-19T05:07:57.155Z",
    "version": 1,
    "fields": [{
            "uid": "fname",
            "value": "john"
        },
        {
            "uid": "lname",
            "value": "test"
        }
    ],
    "class": "first"
}


}
```

After I am using update_by_query to update document I am sending following request to update_by_query:

```
{
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.title = params.title;ctx._source.url = params.url;ctx._source.created_at = params.created_at;ctx._source.updated_at = params.updated_at;ctx._source.version = params.version;ctx._source.fields = params.fields",
        "params": {
            "title": "Demo title",
            "url": "/demo",
            "created_at": "2018-06-19T05:02:38.174Z",
            "updated_at": "2018-06-19T05:07:57.155Z",
            "version": 2,
            "fields": [{
                    "uid": "fname",
                    "value": "vicky"
                },
                {
                    "uid": "lname",
                    "value": "test"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "term": {
                        "_id": "bltde56dd11ba998bab"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "version": {
                            "lt": 2
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But it is giving me status code:409 and following error:

> [documents][bltde56dd11ba998bab]: version conflict, current version
>   [3] is different than the one provided [2]

My document also contain custom version key.
Can anyone help me into this

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of posterity, I'll submit an answer to this old question. The issue is occurring because ElasticSearch's internal version value in the `_version` field is actually 3 in your initial response, not 1.

You are then trying to update the document to using external version value 2, Elastic sees this as a conflict, as internally it thinks version 3 is the most up-to-date version, not version 1. Effectively, something as caused your external version scheme and Elastic's internal version scheme to become out-of-sync.

Also note, the following parameter should be included in your `update` calls to indicate that the operation should follow the rules for external versioning as opposed to Elastic's internal versioning scheme.

`"version_type":external`

There is a subtle but important distinction that needs to be made by specifying this parameter.

> With version_type set to external, Elasticsearch will store the
>   version number as given and will not increment it. Also, instead of
>   checking for an exact match, Elasticsearch will only return a version
>   collision error if the version currently stored is greater or equal to
>   the one in the indexing command.

More information can be on Elastic's version can be found in their [blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-versioning-support)

Answer (score 0):

for me, it was document id. I am using node js elastic-search client, when I create a document I need to pass a document Id,

I was getting version conflict because I was trying to create multiple documents with the same id.

```
    await elasticWrapper.client.create({
          index: ElasticIndexs.Payments,
          id: data.id, // <-- id should be unique 
          body: {
            ...data,
          },
        });
``
```